Delete route in laravel 10 is not working
I'm using laravel 10.x and everything was going good until now because with no reason i created a new models and all routes of the controller are working excepts delete, it can't be reach from postman needer frontend with angular
I'm using the resource in my api.php but I also created an specific one for just delete but it's still not working.
api.php:
 Route::prefix('license')->group(function () {
        Route::delete('companies/{company}', [LicenseCompanyController::class, 'destroy']);
        Route::resource('companies', LicenseCompanyController::class);
        Route::resource('licenses', LicenseController::class);
        route::get('licenses/{license}', [LicenseController::class, 'updateAvailableQuantity']);
    });

Controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\LicenseCompany;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LicenseCompanyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return LicenseCompany::all();
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'link' => 'required',
        ]);

        $licenseCompany = LicenseCompany::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($licenseCompany, 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(LicenseCompany $company)
    {
        return response()->json($company);
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, LicenseCompany $company)
    {
        $company->update($request->all());
        return response()->json($company);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(LicenseCompany $company)
    {
        // $licenseCompany;
        return response()->json(['message' => 'working'], 204);
        // return response()->json($licenseCompany, 204);
    }
}


Model:
class LicenseCompany extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'link',
        'email',
        'phone'
    ];

    public function licenses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(License::class);
    }
}

The route like index and show are working correctly and delete is return 204 with nothing from postman neither an empty array

Your function destroy() only returns JSON, it doesn't delete anything

Yeah because i'm debugging but now I noticed that destroy never can't return any json it only works fine but doesn't show anything

a 204 response is a success response with "no content". I don't know why you want to return content with a 204 response

Now after trying more thing I just figured out that it's not possible to debug the destroy method because it never return a json or anything with https 204, and you just have to make it work and it will do averything, my problem was that in the resource route it was **/{company} but in the method I was waiting destroy(Request LicenseCompany $licenseCompany) but I changed this to destroy(LicenseCompany $company) and without debugging everything is working fine now
